# "INSERT INTO SELECT" vs. "INSERT INTO VALUES ... (SELECT)"

Tags: sql, postgresql

A short question: What is the better way and why?

Using A

```
INSERT INTO someTable(fieldA, fieldB, fieldC)
SELECT 'consA', 'consB', other.value FROM other WHERE XXX
```

or using B:

```
INSERT INTO someTable(fieldA, fieldB, fieldC) 
VALUES ('constA', 'constB', (SELECT other.value FROM other WHERE XXX));
```

or something other ... ?

(`x` can be any condtion to match a single row, Examples are working in postgresql)

Comment: I personally would prefer the  first one

Comment: The first works even if `WHERE XXX` returns multiple rows whereas the second approach will have an error

Comment: i wonder the second one with `VALUES` and `SELECT` even works..usually you would do it per the first example shown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first method is generally better, because the second method runs the risk of doing one of two things:

- Generating an error if the subquery returns more than one row.
- Inserting a `NULL` value if the subquery returns no rows.

Of course, that might be desirable behavior.

In general, `insert . . . select` is more general than `insert . . . values()`.  I prefer the former because it is more powerful and more useful in more situations (including all situations where `values` can be used).